# Dropdownlists and jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

The ASP.NET `DropDownList` has the property `Enabled="false"`, but is it possible from `jQuery` to set the property to `Enabled="true"`?

Answer (score 8):

Do you mean the ASP.NET control DropDownList and the server property "Enabled"?

ASP.NET renders a DropdownList server control with `enable="false"` this way:

```
<select id="myDropDownListId" name="myDropDownListId" disabled="disabled">
```

So, you could use this jQuery snippet to remove that attribute:

```
$('#myDropDownListId').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input").attr("disabled", "false");
```

In this situation, I would assign (I'm assuming that you're using .Net webforms) a CssClass to the input, then use that CssClass as the selector.  Since you can't set the **server** property once the page has been rendered, you have to use the DOM "disabled" parameter; so instead of enabled=true, you'd have to set disabled=false.